# Adding HyperLinks with VBA to create an Explanations tab

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data table and an explanations tab. Because some of the input fields in the data table are hard to understand, I'd like to add hyperlinks (click on the column name and be taken to the proper cell in the Explanations tab) to many of them. So I created the Explanations tab, which may or may not have a matching value from the data table.

So I'm looping through all the column headings on the Calcs (data table) tab, then looking for a matching row in the Info (explanations) tab, and if there's a match, I want to create a hyperlink from Calcs tab heading to Info tab heading.

The error I'm getting is "Expected: named parameter" on the add hyperlinks portion of the code below:

```
Sub AddLinks()
Dim LinkRow As Integer
Dim InfoTab As String
Dim LastCol As Integer

'Row on Calcs tab that column headings are in
LinkRow = 5

'Name of explanations/info tab
InfoTab = "Info"

'Find last column in calcs table
LastCol = Sheets("Calcs").Cells(LinkRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Loop through calcs column, look for corresponding cell in explanations tab, if it isn't
'blank, then add it as a hyperlink
For i = 1 To LastCol
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        If Sheets("Calcs").Cells(LinkRow, i).Value = Sheets(InfoTab).Cells(j, 1).Value Then
        Sheets("Calcs").Cells(LinkRow, i).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range(Sheets(InfoTab).Cells(j, 2).Address), Address:="",
             SubAddress:="'" & InfoTab & "'" & _
             "!" & Cells(j, 2).Address
        End If
   Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any errors running your code.  I would break the code up into smaller easy to test subroutines.

---

```
Sub AddLinks2()
    Const LinkRow As Long = 5
    Dim cell As Range, list As Collection
    Set list = getExplanations
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calcs")
        For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(LinkRow, 1), .Cells(LinkRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            On Error Resume Next
            list.Item cell.Text
            If Err.Number = 0 Then AddHyperlink cell, list(cell.Text)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function getExplanations() As Collection
    Const LinkRow As Long = 5
    Dim cell As Range, list As New Collection

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info")
        For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            On Error Resume Next
            list.Add cell, cell.Text
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    End With
    Set getExplanations = list
End Function

Sub AddHyperlink(Anchor As Range, Target As Range)
    Dim SubAddress As String
    SubAddress = Split(Target.Address(0, 0, xlA1, True), "]")(1)
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Anchor, Address:="", SubAddress:=SubAddress
End Sub
```